# Using errorbars in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot errorbars but they don't show up in my plots for some reason. This is what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xaxis1 = np.array([0.000275039, 0.0002997925, 0.000539195, 0.00099, 0.00079520, 0.001350416, 0.00310023, 0.1537, 0.2323, 0.3586, 0.485887, 0.628496, 0.770675, 0.922438, 1.64721131, 1.66551366, 2.17240912, 3.3533, 4.60510688, 11.57499, 22.04356])
yaxis1 = np.array([9.54e-33, 3.33e-31, 3.78e-31, 2.16e-32, 1.21e-31, 2.43e-31, 1.18e-30, 1.09e-28, 4.62e-28, 9.82e-27, 4.65e-26, 9.45e-26, 1.36e-25, 1.75e-25, 2.67e-25, 1.09e-25, 1.91e-25, 1.17e-25, 6.99e-26, 7.79e-26, 9.14e-26])

plt.yscale('log')
plt.xscale('log')

plt.xlabel('Wavelength (microns)')
plt.ylabel('log (F_v)')

plt.scatter(xaxis1, yaxis1)

c = np.array([0, 0, 3.13e-32, 0, 2.45e-32, 2.86e-32, 1.81e-31, 6.01e-30, 5.11e-29, 9.95e-29, 8.56e-29, 1.74e-28, 2.56e-28, 4.82e-28, 9.0e-27, 2.30e-27, 8.83e-27, 6.49e-28, 5.15e-28, 1.72e-27, 9.42e-27])
plt.errorbar(xaxis1, yaxis1, yerr=c, fmt='.k')
```

It gives the following output:

```
<ErrorbarContainer object of 3 artists>
```

and my plot without the errorbars but lines connecting my scatter points (which is not what I want)

[image: Output plot]

I'd appreciate all the help! Thank you!

Comment: You're doing it correctly. It's just your errors are too small for the bars to show up. Also, `fmt='.k'` does not show the connecting line for me.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I was using fmt='' here but yeah using fmt='.k' doesn't give me the connecting line either. Is there a way I can still show the error bars even if they're that small?

Comment: @zukofirenation, add these `capsize=3, elinewidth=2, zorder=3` right after the fmt in your code.